# coldfusion loop decrement at runtime

Tags: for-loop, coldfusion

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="i">
  #i#<br />
  <cfif i EQ 3>
    <cfset i -= 3 />
    blarg #i# <br >
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

How can i decrease, one decrement value with `forloop`
and my expected output should be

1

2

3

blarg 0

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Comment: you want to use a while loop, not a for loop

Comment: so you want it to loop through 3 twice and every other number once?

Comment: Are you trying to create an infinite loop? If you keep subtracting from the loop counter it will never make it to 10.

Comment: @Miguel-F is right. If you don't want to create an infinite loop you'll need a flag as well to say "i've already hit 3 once, don't decrement it again"

Answer (score 0):

The value of `i` in your example is controlled by the inner workings of `<cfloop>`, and its value simply exposed to the code within the loop block. You can change it within that block, but `<cfloop>` will simply expose the next value in the iteration each time.

To do what you want to do, either use a `for(;;)` loop, or a `<cfloop>` equivalent of same:

```
<cfset i=1>
<cfloop condition="i LTE 10">
    <!--- your logic here--->

    <cfset i++>
</cfloop>
```